# How to use alasql with webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, alasql

I'm failing to use alasql with webpack.

I instalaled alasql

```
npm install --save alasql
```

As mentioned on the [npmjs page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/alasql#webpack-and-browserify) I added this to my `webpack.config.js`:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/(^fs$|xlsx|xls|^path$)/),
```

Then in my code I do

```
import alasql from 'alasql';
```

This causes webpack to fail with this huge error message:

```
WARNING in ./~/alasql/dist/alasql.js
Critical dependencies:
3197:70-77 require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
17317:155-162 require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
 @ ./~/alasql/dist/alasql.js 3197:70-77 17317:155-162

WARNING in ./~/alasql/dist/alasql.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'vertx' in C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\alasql\dist
 @ ./~/alasql/dist/alasql.js 4456:667-677

WARNING in ./~/alasql/dist/alasql-worker.js
Critical dependencies:
70:155-162 require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
 @ ./~/alasql/dist/alasql-worker.js 70:155-162

WARNING in ./~/alasql/dist/alasql-worker.min.js
Critical dependencies:
2:383-390 require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
 @ ./~/alasql/dist/alasql-worker.min.js 2:383-390

WARNING in ./~/alasql/dist/alasql.d.ts
Module parse failed: C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\alasql\dist\alasql.d.ts The keyword 'interface' is reserved (7:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: The keyword 'interface' is reserved (7:0)
    at Parser.pp.raise (C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:923:13)
    at Parser.pp.parseIdent (C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:674:203)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:286:21)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:228:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:207:17)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:154:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:136:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:112:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExpression (C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:88:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseStatement (C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1771:23)
    at Parser.pp.parseTopLevel (C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1666:21)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1632:17)
    at Object.parse (C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:885:44)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\webpack\lib\Parser.js:902:15)
    at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\webpack-core\lib\NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
 @ ./~/alasql/dist ^\.\/.*$

WARNING in ./~/alasql/dist/alasql.min.js
Critical dependencies:
9:17799-17806 require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
14:24021-24028 require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
 @ ./~/alasql/dist/alasql.min.js 9:17799-17806 14:24021-24028

ERROR in ./~/alasql/~/request/~/forever-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'net' in C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\alasql\node_modules\request\node_modules\forever-agent
 @ ./~/alasql/~/request/~/forever-agent/index.js 6:10-24

ERROR in ./~/alasql/~/request/~/forever-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'tls' in C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\alasql\node_modules\request\node_modules\forever-agent
 @ ./~/alasql/~/request/~/forever-agent/index.js 7:10-24

ERROR in ./~/alasql/~/request/~/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'net' in C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\alasql\node_modules\request\node_modules\tough-cookie\lib
 @ ./~/alasql/~/request/~/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js 32:10-24

ERROR in ./~/alasql/~/request/~/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'json-loader' in C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\alasql\node_modules\request\node_modules\tough-cookie\lib
 @ ./~/alasql/~/request/~/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js 38:14-40

ERROR in ./~/alasql/~/request/~/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'net' in C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\alasql\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent
 @ ./~/alasql/~/request/~/tunnel-agent/index.js 3:10-24

ERROR in ./~/alasql/~/request/~/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'tls' in C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\alasql\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent
 @ ./~/alasql/~/request/~/tunnel-agent/index.js 4:10-24

ERROR in ./~/alasql/~/request/~/mime-types/~/mime-db/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'json-loader' in C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\alasql\node_modules\request\node_modules\mime-types\node_modules\mime-db
 @ ./~/alasql/~/request/~/mime-types/~/mime-db/index.js 11:17-37

ERROR in ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'json-loader' in C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\alasql\node_modules\request\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas
 @ ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 4:9-32

ERROR in ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'json-loader' in C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\alasql\node_modules\request\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas
 @ ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 5:14-42

ERROR in ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'json-loader' in C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\alasql\node_modules\request\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas
 @ ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 6:11-36

ERROR in ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'json-loader' in C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\alasql\node_modules\request\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas
 @ ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 7:10-34

ERROR in ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'json-loader' in C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\alasql\node_modules\request\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas
 @ ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 8:11-36

ERROR in ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'json-loader' in C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\alasql\node_modules\request\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas
 @ ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 9:9-32

ERROR in ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'json-loader' in C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\alasql\node_modules\request\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas
 @ ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 10:7-28

ERROR in ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'json-loader' in C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\alasql\node_modules\request\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas
 @ ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 11:7-28

ERROR in ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'json-loader' in C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\alasql\node_modules\request\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas
 @ ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 12:8-30

ERROR in ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'json-loader' in C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\alasql\node_modules\request\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas
 @ ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 13:15-44

ERROR in ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'json-loader' in C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\alasql\node_modules\request\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas
 @ ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 14:12-38

ERROR in ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'json-loader' in C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\alasql\node_modules\request\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas
 @ ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 15:10-34

ERROR in ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'json-loader' in C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\alasql\node_modules\request\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas
 @ ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 16:11-36

ERROR in ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'json-loader' in C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\alasql\node_modules\request\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas
 @ ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 17:12-38

ERROR in ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'json-loader' in C:\Users\epl\developement\woodstore\node_modules\alasql\node_modules\request\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas
 @ ./~/alasql/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 18:11-36
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

Any ideas how to include alasql with webpack?

Comment: It does not make much sense that it looks into alasql-worker.js + alasql-worker.min.js + alasql.d.ts. Have you tried to point to the correct file instead of just "alasql" (node_modules/alasql/dist/alasql.js)?

Answer (score 2):

Checkout https://github.com/agershun/alasql/issues/440 for details but they seem to have updated the regex for the ignore plugin, and you will need to make sure you are using a the json-loader module to parse any json files in the alasql source.

TLDR;
(webpack config)

```
...
plugins: [
    ...
    new IgnorePlugin(/(^fs$|cptable|jszip|xlsx|xls|^es6-promise$|^net$|^tls$|^forever-agent$|^tough-cookie$|cpexcel|^path$)/),
    ...
],
...
loaders: [
    ...
    {
      test: /\.json$/,
      loader: 'json',
      include: [__dirname, '/node_modules']
    },
    ...
]
```